# Problem with drawing an arrow using Pstricks

Tags: pstricks, arrows

I'm trying to draw an arrow by using pstricks, but I cannot do that. 
The code is below:

```
\documentclass{book}‎
\usepackage{pstricks}‎‎
\begin{document}‎‎
\psline[linewidth=20pt]{<-}(2,1)‎‎‎
\end{document}‎
    ‎‎‎
```

What should I change with this code?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does the output look bad or do you have problems compiling it?

Comment: the output is a blank page while there's no error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run it with `xelatex` or alternetively with the sequence `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf`. And then view it with the pdf and not the dvi